# convert to list comprehension

Tags: python

this is my python code

```
mylist = ['a', 'f', 'z']
old_d = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc', 'f': 'fff', 'g':'ggg', 'z':'zzz'} 
new_d = {}
for key in mylist:
    new_d[key] = old_d[key]
```

Can we write the above code using list comprehensions or something similar like

```
new_d[key] = old_d[key] for key in mylist
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.7 and above you can use a dict comprehension:

```
new_d = {key: old_d[key] for key in myList}
```

In Python 2.6 and below, you don't have dict comprehensions must use `dict` with a generator or list comprehension:

```
new_d = dict((key, old_d[key]) for key in myList)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_d = {key: old_d[key] for key in mylist}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension on Python 2.7 and newer:

```
new_d = {k: old_d[k] for k in mylist}
```